# Where is Gellovsasvetgood, Eazasso, Russia?

Tags: palaeography, russia, historical-gazetteer, 1890s, birthplace

My grandfather's military draft registration states that he is from, based on my interpretation of the handwriting, Gellovsasvetgood, Eazasso, Russia.  I can't find any towns with similar spelling.  I looked at a lot of online sites, including Jewish Gen.

What is the correct spelling and location of this town?

[image: Answer to question, "Where were you born"]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.

Answer (score 5):

I think it may be the town of Yelisavetgrad (also spelled Yelisavetgrod), now the city of [Kropyvnytskyi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kropyvnytskyi) in central Ukraine.

If you are able to read Polish, the entry for Elizabetgrod in the [Glossary of the Kingdom of Poland and other Slavic countries](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/pl/Slownik_geograficzny/Tom_II/344) may provide some useful background. (Pages are shown as TIFF images, but with an OCR program, a little (or, perhaps a lot of) patience, and Google Translate you should still be able to read it).